# wrong unique number length

Tags: php

I generate an `unique` security code with this every time user login:

```
$code = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789", 4)), 0, 4);
```

it seems works but sometimes it generate 3 number instead of 4. also this problem occurred with `rand()` in past, then i decide to use `str_shuffle` + `str_repeat`.

also i insert this code in `db` with integer data type and length is 6.

*what did i wrong or missed?
or is it a bug?*

Comment: Are you converting the result to an integer later? That would do it 10% of the time (when the string version starts with `"0"`).

Comment: @Paulpro unfortunately no, so you say: if i convert the result to integer or remove zero from this string help to fix this issue? i'll try.

Comment: No, that is not what they are saying. Your code does not seem to reproduce the result; so it is more likely that you are _using_ the code "wrong" somewhere ... but you did not show us what you're actually doing with it.

Comment: this part so huge! i can't post it here, as i said i use this to generate four random digit (as a security code) every time user login, `sendSMS($tel, $code);` the code will sms to user phone number, sendSMS function is a api to send sms and i insert this code to `db` with `SQL INSERT` @CBroe

Comment: _"and i insert this code to db with SQL INSERT"_ - then that's likely the part where you're actually doing things wrong (because the PHP snippet you have shown _always_ produces as 4-digit code.) Did you use a wrong data type, forget to quote the value, ...?

Comment: What is the data type of the column into which you are inserting `$code`?  If it's an integer type, then I suspect @Paulpro nailed it in the first comment.

Comment: @hunteke it is `integer` and length is `6`

Comment: @CBroe `quote ` is set, data type is integer with 6 length,it's a common thing when you want to insert this code to `db` you should use integer, isn't it?

Comment: @pedram It's an integer type; in the absence of other information, I think this is *exactly* the issue.  You are generating a string of digits, then inserting them into an *integer* field.  The DB or DB driver will convert your string of characters to an integer, thereby removing the leading zero.

Comment: seems found the problem, you know what, i didn't thought this was cause of problem otherwise i mention it in question, anyway. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're storing the result in an integer field, it's not being stored as separate digits, just as a number. So it doesn't know anything about leading zeroes.

When you later retrieve the value, you can convert it to a string with leading zeroes using the `str_pad` function:

```
$code = str_pad($num, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

The other option would be to change the datatype in the database to `CHAR(4)` instead of `INT`.

Comment: what is `$num` here?

Comment: It's the number you retrieve from the database.

Comment: I got it, i don't retrieve any number for `db` actually i insert but i got you solution `$code = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789", 4)), 0, 4);
$code = str_pad($code, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $code;` and this also works fine. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to use `str_pad` with `$code`, it's already a string. The problem only happens when you store the code in an integer in the database.

Comment: well, i understand better now, so i just need use your code just for inserting to `db` while i don't want change dataype. Thanks

Comment: If the datatype is number, the leading zeroes will be ignored when you insert into the DB. You need to use my code after you retrieve from the DB.

Answer (score 3):

While I can't immediately say why your code sometimes returns only 3 digits, I find myself wondering why you don't create this 4-digit (call it a PIN?) code through the more numerically appropriate `rand`?  For example, since you are going for a 4-digit PIN (between 0000 and 9999), I might write it like:

```
$code = rand(0, 9999);
$code = substr("000$code", -4);
```

That is much clearer as to its purpose (generate a random number, guarantee it's 4 digits), and less esoteric than `str_repeat`/`str_shuffle`.

EDIT (after learning `$code` is inserted into an integer DB field)

Why is your random *string* of 4 digits sometimes turning into 3 digits?  Because you are inserting the value into an integer column.  Either the DB or the DB Driver will attempt the moral equivalent of:

```
$code_to_insert = (int)$code;
```

at which point, if the number is less than 1000, you would get three digits.

Further, if you run your code enough times as it currently stands, you should get PIN lengths of 2 and 1 as well:

```
   0 -    9 = (  10 / 10000)   ->  0.1% of the time
  10 -   99 = (  90 / 10000)   ->  0.9% of the time
 100 -  999 = ( 900 / 10000)   ->  9.0% of the time
1000 - 9999 = (9000 / 10000)   -> 90.0% of the time
```

A possible fix, given the current setup of your code and DB, might be to ensure the PIN length when you pull it *out* of the DB.  You could use the same trick as above:

```
$sql = "SELECT code FROM ...";
...
$code = $row['code'];
$code = substr("000$code", -4);
```

Comment: `mt_rand()` is much better alternative than `rand() `, otherwise it is nice solution.

Comment: @bodi0 Better how? or via what metric?  If he needs a cryptographically secure random, then we're both wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it fixed the issue. but there is one question, asking for my own knowledge, this part `substr("000$code", -4);` `000` before `$code` What does it do exactly?

Comment: @pedram It uses PHP's iterpolation to create a string that is at least 4 characters long.  In the "worst" case, `"000$code"` becomes `"0000"`.  In the other extreme case, it becomes `"0009999"`.  `-4` takes the last 4 characters of that string, whatever they may be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$code = str_pad($num, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```